# How to use automatic retry in Google Drive / Fetcher services in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, google-drive-api, http-status-code-500

### The problem

I am using [google-api-objectivec-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client) library to work with Google Drive API.
I am creating 10 folders inside `appDataFolder` (for example) without any delays and it is too fast and I am constantly getting **errors for 9/10** of my requests:

```
Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=500 "(Internal Error)" UserInfo={error=Internal Error, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Internal Error)

some times these:
Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "(User Rate Limit Exceeded)" UserInfo={error=User Rate Limit Exceeded, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(User Rate Limit Exceeded),
```

Most likely, it is related to *"spamming"* or *userRateLimit* exceptions, because it easily can be fixed by "sleeps" (have reproduced this many times).

### Suggested solution

[Google suggest](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors#standard_errors) to retry request with such kind of errors, even it provides great API to do it automatically.
According to [documentation](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki#automatic-retry):

> GTL service classes and the GTMSessionFetcher class provide a mechanism for automatic retry of a few common network and server errors, with appropriate increasing delays between each attempt. You can turn on the automatic retry support for a GTL service by setting the retryEnabled property.
>
> ```
> // Turn on automatic retry of some common error results
> service.retryEnabled = YES;
> ```
>
> The default errors retried are http status 408 (request timeout), 503 (service unavailable), and 504 (gateway timeout), NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost, and NSURLErrorTimedOut. You may specify a maximum retry interval other than the default of 1 minute, and can provide an optional retry selector to customize the criteria for each retry attempt.

But error with status 500 is not in default list. So, I tried to use this:

```
// Retry selector is optional for retries.
// If present, it should have the signature:
//   -(BOOL)ticket:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket willRetry:(BOOL)suggestedWillRetry forError:(NSError *)error
// and return YES to cause a retry.  Note that unlike the fetcher retry
// selector, this selector's first argument is a ticket, not a fetcher.

GTLService.retrySelector
```

I have created a method which constantly returns `YES`, but **it never get called** and as a result request with errors are not retried.

### Question

How to use automatic retry for `google-api-objectivec-client`?

**Update.** Code sample to reproduce the issue:

```
- (void) reproduceTheIssue: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *) authorizer {

    GTLServiceDrive * driveService = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc] init];
    driveService.retryEnabled = true;
    driveService.authorizer = authorizer;
    //    driveService.fetcherService.retryEnabled = YES; //this also doesn't help
    //    driveService.retrySelector =  @selector(ticket:willRetry:forError:);
    const int DELAY = 0;
    const int NUMBER_OF_FOLDERS = 50;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_FOLDERS; i++) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, DELAY * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            GTLDriveFile * nestedFolder = [GTLDriveFile object];
            NSString * folderName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"folder-number-%i", i];
            nestedFolder.name = folderName;
            nestedFolder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
            nestedFolder.parents = @[@"appDataFolder"];

            GTLQueryDrive * query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesCreateWithObject: nestedFolder uploadParameters: nil];
            [driveService executeQuery: query completionHandler: ^(GTLServiceTicket * ticket, GTLDriveFile * updatedFile, NSError * error) {
                if (error == nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Successfully created a folder %@", updatedFile);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to a folder: %@ error: %@", folderName, error);
                }
            }];
        });
    }
}

- (BOOL) ticket: (GTLServiceTicket *) ticket willRetry: (BOOL) suggestedWillRetry forError: (NSError *) error {
    NSLog(@"I will never be called :( with this arguments ticket: %@, willRetry: %i, error :%@", ticket, suggestedWillRetry, error);
    return YES;
}
```

**Update Update** The issue was discussed at [library's GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/184). Short answer: it is not possible to retry these error automatically. It should be managed programmatically by user in `handlers`.

> The retry logic is in the http fetcher class, so the retries only reflect errors that show up during network requests.

Comment: I get the state you are trying to say right now, one thing though, the main question is ***How to use automatic retry for google-api-objectivec-client?***, yet the [answer](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki#automatic-retry) to it is already included in post itself? Do you mean on how properly handle error 500? If not, can you elaborate?

Comment: @sept, Yes the question is how to use this retry mechanism properly, I have done everything according documentation, but it didn't work. So, I have two questions: 1) How to enable retry; 2) How to use custom selector to retry 500 error (it is not in the list to retry by default)
I will update the question with an example, to make it more clear.

Comment: I get what you're aiming for. Customizing the *automatic retry* to consider error 500. But as per the Google Suggestion link, it already includes [How to Handle 500/503 responses](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors#500) by Implementing Exponential Backoff. And I don't think it's really a good idea to retry the after the 500 error. As per the suggested action: ***Do not retry this query more than once.***